# How do I hide overflowed floated elements using css?

Tags: css-float, css

I have a block container element which contains block elements and then some floated elements which are taller than the parent container. I want to use the height set by the block elements and cut off the floated elements which are taller.

My thought was to use overflow: hidden, but lo! it creates a new block formatting context so that the parent no longer uses the height of the block elements, but uses the height of the floated elements so nothing is actually hidden.

I want a more robust solution than just adding a fixed height and hoping the block content fits, and yet I don't want to do this with JS.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you got an image, a fiddle, a site showing what you want / your attempts so far?

Comment: OK, so in this pen, I want to clip the floated image at the height of the top container while retaining the content reflow properties of the floated image in the top container (so absolute positioning is out)   http://codepen.io/tscott2/pen/kBLdn

Comment: You lost me a bit on the absolute positioning out part.  This isn't what you want? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgkGr

Comment: That'd work well, except I need the floated element behavior. I'm using this technique for irregular text wrapping: http://www.csstextwrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your circumstances, you could add

```
position:absolute;
```

to the floated element

http://jsfiddle.net/E4LnG/1/

however, then the floated element is no longer floating...

I think it would be better though, to reconsider what you are trying to do and figure out an entirely different approach. If you want to hide an element, it's best to reference them by class and use

```
display:none;
```

it seems hackish to me to try and hide elements that happen to be floating...

Answer (score 0):

If you have block elements which are not floating they will take the whole row, therefore the floated elements whill drop under the nonfloated, no matter the float. (like in ok's fiddle). Please, explain a little better, maybe really with an image, what you really want